# Combining multiple pointcuts AspectJ returns adviceDidNotMatch warning

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I am trying to combining multiple pointcuts of getter and setter to create an advice that will be executed if both pointcuts are executed. I have tried in normal AspectJ class and annotation @Aspect class but still it gives me warning adviceDidNotMatch and eventually the advice is not executed. Strangely if I change && (AND) with || (OR) it works, but why && doesn't work at all?

Here is the advice declared in normal AspectJ class.

```
package testMaven;

pointcut getter() : execution(* testMaven.testing.getDd(..));
before() : getter(){
    System.out.println("test get");
}

pointcut setter() : execution(* testMaven.testing.setDd(..));
before() : setter(){
    System.out.println("test set");
}

pointcut combine(): getter() && setter();

before(): combine(){
    System.out.println("testing combine");
}
}
```

Here is the advice declared in annotation @Aspect class

```
package testMaven;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;


@Aspect
public class aspecter {

    @Pointcut("call (*  testMaven.testing.getDd(..))")
    public void getter(){

    }

    @Pointcut("call (*  testMaven.testing.setDd(..))")
    public void setter(){}


    @Pointcut("execution (*  testMaven.tester.setZ(..))")
    public void setterZ(){}

    @Before("setterZ()")
    public void settingZ(){
        System.out.println("before set Z");
    }

    @Pointcut("getter() && setter()")
    public void getterSetter(){}

    @After("getterSetter()")
    public void testerd(){
        System.out.println("works");
    }

    @Pointcut("getter() && setterZ()")
    public void getterSetter2(){}

    @After("getterSetter2()")
    public void testinger(){
        System.out.println("ok");
    }

}
```

Here is the testing class that I want to be advised:

```
package testMaven;

public class testing {

    public int dd;

    public int getDd() {
        return dd;
    }

    public void setDd(int dd) {
        this.dd = dd;
    }
}


package testMaven;

public class testing {

    public int dd;


    public int getDd() {
        return dd;
    }


    public void setDd(int dd) {
        this.dd = dd;
    }


    public void aa(int a){
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

And here is the main class:

```
package testMaven;

public class MainApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        testing test = new testing();
        test.aa(2);
        test.setDd(3);
        tester et = new tester();
        et.setZ(3);
        et.printNo(1000);
        System.out.println(test.getDd());



    }

}
```

Is there something wrong with my code? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to use `@After("getter() || Setter()")` instead of `@After("getterSetter()")`

Comment: @uniknow using || will execute the advice if one of the advice is executed and for this case i need to use &&. || is recognized by advice but && is not.

Comment: Don't understand the feedback. I assume you want to print `works` when getter or setter is invoked.

Comment: @uniknow I want to print works when getter and setter are invoked.

Comment: How do you expect that getter and setter are invoked at the same time?

Comment: @uniknow In the real life scenario I was thinking that getter and setter are from different classes, but for simplicity purpose I just use getter and setter from one same class. I also have tried to use different classes of getter and setter but still not working. I will update the code above to show from different classes

Comment: Are you using AspectJ which is applied during compilation?

Comment: @uniknow yeah I did use it but still warning of the advice did not match. I saw in the book of AspectJ said it is possible

Comment: Could you change `@Before("setterZ()")` into `@Before("execution (* *.setZ(..))") and let me know what happens.

Comment: @uniknow it's working fine as setZ() method is executed in the Main class therefore advice of setZ is also executed

Comment: Could you switch within `@Pointcut("getter() && setterZ()")` the getter and setter, so it becomes ' @Pointcut("setterZ() && getter()")'. To be honest I don't think this will work either because i don't foresee how the getter call and setter call can come to a single joinpoint.

Comment: @uniknow still the same i'm afraid, what i am thinking is that you are using getter from class 1 and setter from class 2, such as et.setZ(test.getDd());. Actually this question is an alternative method from the real problem as I have another problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37563258/get-object-instantiation-and-access-its-related-attributes-and-methods-with-aspe), maybe you could help me on this one. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You asked if there is something wrong with your code. The answer is yes. The two pointcuts `setter()` and `getter()` are mutually exclusive. Thus combining them with `&&` - i.e. creating an intersection of two mutually disjunct sets of joinpoints - logically leads to an empty result set. Ergo your combined pointcut does not match. You should use `||` as uniknow suggested in his/her comment.

If you want to achieve something else, please explain it in a comprehensible way, if necessary by giving examples, in a comment or by updating your question. I really did not get what you really want.

Comment: it's only an example of what I had in mind, I tried to use other unrelated methods with && but still it gives me an error

Comment: That does not answer my question. I know it is what you had in mind, but nobody understands what that should be. Sorry, if you cannot explain what you acttually want, I cannot help you. Your code just does not make any sense. Bye.