# Get Object Instantiation and Access Its Related Attributes and Methods with AspectJ

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

Can we get an object created or instantiated using AspectJ and access object's attributes and methods? I know with AspectJ we can get input parameters of the methods but will it be the same with the object creation?

For example, in the code it has this line

```
testing test = new testing();
```

And I would like to get the test object using AspectJ and access the method and variables of class testing(), like method aa().

Here is the code for testing class.

```
package testMaven;

public class testing {

    public int dd;


    public int getDd() {
        return dd;
    }


    public void setDd(int dd) {
        this.dd = dd;
    }


    public void aa(int a){
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

**Real Coding Problem**

The above coding is only merely an example of the abstract problem I currently have the problem. Thanks to the answer below, it works in this example, but in the real project that I have it is not working. Basically the code as follow:

```
@After("execution(de.hpi.cloudraid.dto.control.storedObjectService.CreateFileFinalResponseDto.new(..))")
    public void constructorInvocation(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        CreateFileFinalResponseDto instance = (CreateFileFinalResponseDto) joinPoint.getTarget();
        System.err.println("testing new object creation");
        System.err.println("id upload = " + instance.getFileObjectID());

    }
```

But the code is not working as it gives the warning of advice has not been applied (xlint : adviceDidNotMatch). CreateFileFinalResponseDto class is basically from different project called shared and I already include the shared project in the pom.xml and AspectJ dependencies and plugin as follow:

```
   <dependencies>
            <!-- Project -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>shared</artifactId>
                <version>${project.server.version}</version>
            </dependency> 
    ...
    <!-- AspectJ -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
            </dependency>
...

     <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <complianceLevel>${java.version}</complianceLevel>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>AspectJ-Classes</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>AspectJ-Test-Classes</id>
                        <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To catch class instantiate one could use the following aspect:

```
@Aspect
public class Interceptor {
    /**
     * Matches constructor testMaven.testing.
     * <p/>
     * *NOTE:* This will only work when class compiled with aspectj.
     */
    @After("execution(* testMaven.testing.new(..))")
    public void constructorInvocation(JoinPoint joinPoint)
            throws Throwable {
        testing instance = (testing) joinPoint.getTarget();
        instance.aa(2);
    }
}
```

In case you want to catch the instantiate `Before` there won't be a instance of course.

Comment: i dont understand the usage of Object instance and Object[] argument. Can the instance object used to access the class method and variables, i.e. instance.aa(5) (see the code above) ? Btw based on your answer, i should put like execution (testMaven.testing.new(..)) right?

Comment: Modified example a bit so that it more matches what you expect.

Comment: it works for this example case, thanks! but in the real life problem, it doesn't work as it gives warning advicedidnotmatch. The adviced class is from different packages but I already included it in the maven dependencies

Comment: Don't understand your comment. Why did the aspect not match? (if you want to match another specific constructor of class change `@After("execution(* testMaven.testing.new(..))")`.

Comment: I see that the aspect to catch the instantiation is as follows `@After("execution(de.hpi.cloudraid.dto.control.storedObjectService.CreateFileFinalResponseDto.new(..))")`. Difference with the working one seems to be the * in front. Can you change the join point into `@After("execution(* de.hpi.cloudraid.dto.control.storedObjectService.CreateFileFinalResponseDto.new(..))")` and see whether it works.

Comment: it still doesn't work and gives me same warning and new error "Syntax error on token "execution(* de.hpi.cloudraid.dto.control.storedObjectService.CreateFileFi‌​nalResponseDto.new(..))", "method name (not constructor)" expected"

Comment: Nevermind that, I already fixed the problem as I need to tweak it a little based on your answer on my previous posts. Thank you very much.